# Cannot assign to videoZoomFactor of AVCaptureDevice

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

Hi I'm trying to set the zoomFactor of my camera to 1.0 so it display as much of what a camera could take in as possible as I realized that the iPhone's camera app can "see" more than what my camera can see built using AVFoundation.

However, when trying to set the videoZoomFactor to 1.0 I got this error
"Cannot assign to videoZoomFactor in device"
I'm not sure why it happened and searching through the internet doesn't yield any result therefore I'm asking for help here.

```
 if device.position == .Back{
            device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
            device.videoZoomFactor = CGFloat(1.0)
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
            inputCameraBack = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice, error: nil)
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have solved your problem by now but the issue appears to be caused by`device` not being cast to an `AVCaptureDevice` when you set the `videoZoomFactor`. 
First cast it then set the `videoZoomFactor` then create the `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with your `AVCaptureDevice`.